# How to capture chat response with LoadRunner?

Tags: asynchronous, chat, response, polling, loadrunner

I'm looking to load test a message server with Loadrunner. On one end of the message server it's a web application, and on the other end it's a desktop client.

web application <--> message server <--> desktop application

I have recorded a script from the web application, and the script is currently sending messages to the desktop client fine.

script >--send message--> message server >--> desktop application = OK

I'm looking to capture messages sent from the desktop client in the script, but I'm having trouble trying to capture a response from the server. Any ideas?

The web application is polling every second for messages from the desktop application.

I'm pretty new to this, so I apologize if this is a little vague. Please feel free to ask any questions, and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: What is the communications protocol mechanism used by the client?

Answer (score 0):

When you record a script in VuGen (let's say, using Web HTTP protocol), the "Start recording" dialog gives you options to record either a browser or an application. In the latter case you're prompted to select application's .exe file, and then it should be recorded. Have you tried this?